# Segmentation fault in the code to convert infix expression to postfix

Tags: c++, stack, infix-notation

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
struct stackint{
    int top;
    int size;
    int a[50];
    void push(int x){
        if(top==size-1){
            cout<<"stack is full"<<"\n";
        }
        else{
            a[++top]=x;
        }
    }
    int pop(){
        return a[top--];
    }
    bool isempty(){
        if(top==-1){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    bool isfull(){
        if(top==size-1){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    int peek(){
        return a[top];
    }
};
struct stackchar{
    int top;
    int size;
    char c[1000];
    void push(char x){
        if(top==size-1){
            cout<<"stack is full"<<"\n";
        }
        else{
            c[++top]=x;
        }
    }
    char pop(){
        return c[top--];
    }
    bool isempty(){
        if(top==-1){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    bool isfull(){
        if(top==size-1){
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
    char peek(){
        char s= c[this->top];
        return s;
    }
};
int precedence(char s){
    if(s=='+'||s=='-'){
        return 1;
    }
    if(s=='*'||s=='/'){
        return 2;
    }
}
void infixtoprefix(stackchar &c,string infix){
    int l=infix.length();
    int i=0;
    while(infix[i]=='\0'){
        c.push(infix[i]);
        i++;
    }
    string rev;
    i=l-1;
    while(i!=0){
        rev+=c.pop();
        i--;
    }
    i=0;
    while(rev[i]=='\0'){
        if(rev[i]=='('){
            rev[i]=')';
        }
        else if(rev[i]==')'){
            rev[i]='(';
        }
        i++;
    }
    i=0;
    string res;
    while(rev[i]=='\0'){
        if(isdigit(rev[i])){
            res+=rev[i];
        }
        if(rev[i]=='('){
            c.push('(');
        }
        if(rev[i]==')'){
            while(c.peek()!='('){
                res+=c.pop();
            }
            res+=c.pop();
        }
        else{
            if(precedence(c.peek())>rev[i]){
                while(precedence(c.peek())>rev[i]){
                    res+=c.pop();
                }
                c.push(rev[i]);
            }
            else{
                c.push(rev[i]);
            }
        }
        i++;
    }
    while(!c.isempty()){
        res+=c.pop();
    }
    i=l-1;
    while(i!=0){
        cout<<res[i];
        i--;
    }
    cout<<"\n";
}
int main(){
    stackchar c;
    c.top=-1;
    c.size=30;
    string infix="3+4*5+6";
    infixtoprefix(c,infix);
    return 0;
}
```

I'm trying to implement code for converting infix expression to a postfix expression. The error message is given below.
I don't understand where I've done wrong.

**Error Message:** *Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0000000000401304 in stackchar::peek (this=0x7fffffffe7e0) at main.cpp:62
62              char s= c[this->top];
(gdb)*

Comment: You are using gdb. Why don't you investigate the current values?

Comment: *I don't understand where I've done wrong* -- Your program has a bug or multiple bugs.  It is expected that programs written will have bugs -- you should be prepared to address them, and not be surprised.

Comment: Also, didn't your compiler warn you about the `precedence` function not returning a value for all paths?  What happens if `s` is none of those characters -- what do you return?

Comment: Look closely at the condition of  most of your while loops. There are most likely other bugs.

Comment: This might be worth reading: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/